# Python - Regex - combination of letters and numbers (undefined length)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get a File-ID from a [text file](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1477333/000119312519222176/0001193125-19-222176.txt). In the above example the filename is `d735023ds1.htm` which I want to get in order to build another url. Those filenames differ however in their length and I would need a universal regex expression to cover all possibilities.

#### Example filenames

d804478ds1a.htm.
d618448ds1a.htm.
d618448.htm

#### My code

```py
for cik in leftover_cik_list:

    r = requests.get(filing.url)
    content = str(r.content)
    fileID = None

    for line in content.split("\n"):
    
        if fileID == None:
            fileIDIndex = line.find("<FILENAME>")
            
            if fileIDIndex != -1:
                trimmedText = line[fileIDIndex:]
                result = RegEx.search(r"^[\w\d.htm]*$", trimmedText)
            
                if result:
                    fileID = result.group()

    print ("fileID",fileID)

    document_link = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/{0}/{1}/{2}.htm".format(cik, accession_number, fileID)

    print ("Document Link to S-1:", document_link)
```

Comment: So is the format always d 1-6 numbers and ends in .htm? With possibly ds1a in it

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

...
result = re.search('^d\d{1,6}.+\.htm$', trimmedText)
if result:
    fileID = result.group()
```

^d      = Start with a d

\d{1,6} = Look for 1-6 digits, if there could be an unlimited amount of digits replace with \d{1,}

.+      = Wild card

\.htm$ = End in .htm

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast help. Two things when I try your answer: (1) yellow mark: Anomalous backslash in string and (2) result of search "None" thus its not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I put the result in the wrong bit. Try the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `re.match()` which searches for a pattern at the beginning of the input string. Also, your regex is not good, you have to add an anti-shash before `.`, as point means "any character" in regex.

```py
import re
result = re.match('[\w]+\.htm', trimmedText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```py
import re
files = [
    "d804478ds1a.htm",
    "d618448ds1a.htm",
    "d618448.htm"
]
for f in files:
    match = re.search(r"d\w+\.htm", f)
    print(match.group())

d804478ds1a.htm
d618448ds1a.htm
d618448.htm
```

The assumptions in the above are that the file name starts with a `d`, ends with `.htm` and contains only letters, digits and underscores.